# The product of Hausdorff spaces is Hausdorff

Tags: general-topology, separation-axioms, product-space

I'm confused how it can be true that the product of an infinite number of Hausdorff spaces $X_\alpha$ can be Hausdorff.

If $\prod_{\alpha \in J} X_\alpha$ is a product space with product topology, the basis elements consists of of products $\prod_{\alpha \in J} U_{\alpha}$ where $U_{\alpha}$ would equal $X_{\alpha}$ for all but finitely many $\alpha$'s. If this is the case and we had two distinct points, $x$ and $y$, in $\prod_{\alpha \in J} X_{\alpha}$ and a basis element, $B_x$ containing $x$ then In looking for a basis element,$B_y$ that contains $y$ but is disjoint from $B_x$ then for every $\alpha$ such that the open set $U_\alpha$ of $B_x$ is equal to $X_\alpha$ the open set $U_\alpha$ for $B_y$ would have to be empty. But then it couldn't possibly contain $y$. (or any other point of $\prod_{\alpha \in J} X_\alpha$ for that matter). How then is it possible that $\prod_{\alpha \in J} X_\alpha$ is Hausdorff in the product topology?

What am I missing?

Comment: Two products $\prod_{\alpha\in J} U_\alpha$ and $\prod_{\alpha\in J}V_\alpha$ are disjoint when there is (at least) _one_ $\alpha_0 \in J$ such that $U_{\alpha_0} \cap V_{\alpha_0} = \varnothing$.

Comment: Ah, I see. I'm so stupid I wasn't thinking about that right. Thank you.

Answer (score 51):

If $x$ and $y$ are **distinct** points of $\prod_{\alpha\in J}X_\alpha$, then there is at least one $\alpha_0\in J$ on which they differ, meaning that $x_{\alpha_0}\ne y_{\alpha_0}$. $X_{\alpha_0}$ is Hausdorff, so there are open sets $U_{\alpha_0}$ and $V_{\alpha_0}$ in $X_{\alpha_0}$ such that $x_{\alpha_0}\in U_{\alpha_0}$, $y_{\alpha_0}\in V_{\alpha_0}$, and $U_{\alpha_0}\cap V_{\alpha_0}=\varnothing$. Now let $U_\alpha=V_\alpha=X_\alpha$ for each $\alpha\in J\setminus\{\alpha_0\}$, let $U=\prod_{\alpha\in J}U_\alpha$, and let $V=\prod_{\alpha\in J}V_\alpha$; then $U$ and $V$ are basic open sets in $\prod_{\alpha\in J}X_\alpha$, $x\in U$, $y\in V$, and $U\cap V=\varnothing$. The only statement there that might not be immediately evident is that $U\cap V=\varnothing$; to see this, note that if $z\in U\cap V$, then $z_{\alpha_0}\in U_{\alpha_0}\cap V_{\alpha_0}=\varnothing$, so no such $z$ can exist.

Thus, $\prod_{\alpha\in J}X_\alpha$ is Hausdorff.

Comment: In the third line, do you mean $ U_{a_0} \cap V_{a_0}$ instead of $ U_{a_0} \cap V_{a_0}$?

Comment: @Siyanda: I mean $U_{\alpha_0}\cap V_{\alpha_0}$ instead of $U_{\alpha_0}\cap U_{\alpha_0}$. :-) Thanks; fixed.

Comment: Oh, yes! Haha, that's what I meant too. :)

Comment: In the second and third lines, shouldn't it be $x_{\alpha_0}\in U_{\alpha_0}$ and $y_{\alpha_0}\in V_{\alpha_0}$?

Comment: Can I ask a question, If we take the box and not the product topology does this still hold?

Comment: @HossienSahebjame: Yes. If $\tau$ is the product topology, and $\tau_1$ is the box topology, then $\tau\subseteq\tau_1$, so the fact that $\tau$ is Hausdorff immediately implies that the finer topology $\tau_1$ is Hausdorff.

Comment: one more thing, this uses the fact that: If $B \cap C = \emptyset$ then $(A \times B) \cap (A \times C) = \emptyset$? sorry I just want to know every single reason for every single move.

Comment: @HossienSahebjame: Yes, it does.

Comment: If $x$ and $y$ differ in an *infinite* number of indices, is it still true that $U$ and $V$ are basic open sets in the product topology?

Comment: @pyridoxal_trigeminus: yes: They differ on only one coordinate, $\alpha_0$.