# Example of a Baire metric space which is not completely metrizable

Tags: general-topology, metric-spaces, baire-category

I know that some Baire metric spaces are not complete metric spaces but all examples, that I know, are completely metrizable. Help me to find an example of Baire metric space which is not completely metrizable. $[$Please give some short proofs or references$]$

Comment: See [Completely Metrizable Space and Baire Theorem](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/150472).

Answer (score 12, accepted):

A classic example is the open upper half plane with the rationals on the $x$-axis:

$X = \{(x,y) \in \mathbb{R}^2: y >0 \text{ or } y=0, x \in \mathbb{Q}\}$ in the Euclidean metric.

This is Baire as it has an open dense Baire subspace $\mathbb{R} \times (0,\infty)$ (which *is* completely metrisable) and not completely metrisable as it has a closed homeomorphic copy of $\mathbb{Q}$.

Comment: If I'm not wrong, $X=\mathbb{Q}\times (0,\infty)$, then considering $U_n=X\setminus \{r_n\}\times (0, \infty)$ we got $\cap U_n = \phi$

Comment: @Offlaw $\mathbb{Q}\times (0,\infty)$ is irrelevant.

Comment: I got it. $X=\mathbb{R} \times (0,\infty) \cup \mathbb{Q} \times \{0\}$.

Comment: @Offlaw indeed. That’s the space